# Retrieving From WPF AccessDatabase formatting

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, formatting

I trying to format the data that I'm extracting from the Access Database to look something like the format below from the database.

`ID Name (Age)
Company Name
Handphone Number
NRIC`

Is it possible to do this in a gridview or inside a rich textbox in Visual Studio WPF?

Currently my Code is:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ToString();
con.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select ID,Name,Age,Company,Handphone,NRIC FROM Customers WHERE Name = @txtSearch";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtSearch", txtSearch.Text);
cmd.Connection = con;
OleDbDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
grid1.ItemsSource = rd;
```

Comment: You've already tackled the hard part. what you should do next is put that data in a domain or viewmodel (if you intend to use a domain, then you should still use a separate viewmodel according to MVVM design principles), then bind that to your wpf controls.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do either of that can you assist me on it?

Comment: That is rather beyond the scope of a single question. i suggest you start by picking up some learning material on WPF, Data binding etc. first.